# Webpage in the same row pictures

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want this photos in the same row what should i change ?
[image]

I tried float left and other commands but one picture is staying in the lower right corner.

```
<section id="services">
<div class="container">
<div class="row wow fadeInUp">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="resimler/bimplus.jpg" class="wow fadeInRight">
<h4 class="wow fadeInRight delay-2s">BIMPLUS</h4>
<p>HNP</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="resimler/brighe.jpg" class="wow fadeInRight" height="80px">
<h4 class="wow fadeInRight delay-2s">BRIDGE</h4>
<p>HNP</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="resimler/precast.jpg" class="wow fadeInRight">
<h4 class="wow fadeInRight delay-2s">PRECAST</h4>
<p>HNP</p>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="resimler/precast.jpg" class="wow fadeInRight">
<h4 class="wow fadeInRight delay-2s">PRECAST</h4>
<p>HNP</p>
</div>
</div>    
</div>    
</section>
```

and style.css file i tried margin-left , float left but i couldn't change.

```
#services
{
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
#services .col-md-4
{
    padding: 20px;
}
#services .col-md-4 h4
{
    padding: 5px;
}
#services .col-md-4 img
{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#services .col-md-4 p
{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: You're not closing the third column before opening the fourth one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` to fix this issue because it's more flexable, that's an example:

```html
<section class="services">
  <div class="service">
    <img src="service.jpg">
    <h3>Service</h3>
    <p>Service Description...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <img src="service.jpg">
    <h3>Service</h3>
    <p>Service Description...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <img src="service.jpg">
    <h3>Service</h3>
    <p>Service Description...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <img src="service.jpg">
    <h3>Service</h3>
    <p>Service Description...</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
.services {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 40px;
}

.services .service {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can read about flexbox here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

add </ div> after < p>HNP</ p> to close your tag

then, change **col-md-4** to **col-md-3** so that you can get 4 columns